# Uncountable orthonormal system in Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I need an example of a Hilbert space in which the following does *not* hold for all $x$:

$$
x=\sum_k^{\infty} \langle x,u_k \rangle u_k.
$$

That is, there are elements that are not expressible as countable sums. It is obvious that this can only happen in the case of a Hilbert space that admits an uncountable orthonormal system.

Is the completion of quasi-periodic functions an example of such spaces?

Answer (score 3):

If $H$ is a Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\{u_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}$, then for all $h\in H$, the set $B=\{\alpha\in A: \langle h,u_\alpha\rangle \neq 0 \}$ is countable, and $h$ can be written as the countable sum $h=\sum\limits_{\alpha\in B}\langle h,u_\alpha\rangle u_\alpha$.

Comment: @Anthony: Because $\|h\|^2=\sum|\langle h,u_\alpha\rangle|^2$.  If there were uncountably many nonzero terms, there would be an $n$ with infinitely many terms greater than $1/n$, hence the series would not converge.

Comment: I just realised myself that the very *definition* of $u_\alpha$ being an orthonormal basis is that every $h$ can be written as a countable linear combination.

Comment: @Anthony: That definition is not usual to me.  An onb is a maximal orthonormal subset.  But either way it is a consequence that each element is a countable "linear combination" of onb elements.

Comment: @JonasMeyer Doesn't the proof of $\lVert h \rVert^2 = \sum|\langle h, u_\alpha \rangle|^2$ depend on the fact that $B$ is countable? (I.e. isn't that a circular argument?)

Comment: @Anakhand: Perhaps! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the space of real-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$ with the inner-product given by
$$
\langle f, g\rangle = \lim_{R\to \infty} \int_{-R}^{+R} f(x)g(x)dx
$$
and let $H$ denote the Hilbert space of equivalence classes of functions whose induced norm is finite (modulo functions whose norm is zero).

Now note that $\sin(ax)$ and $\sin(bx)$ are orthogonal in this space if $a\neq b$. Hence, $\{\sin(ax) : a\in \mathbb{R}\}$ forms an uncountable orthogonal set, and so $H$ cannot be separable.

An additional interesting example is that of $L^2$ spaces themselves. See [this discussion.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42310/when-is-l2x-separable)

Comment: I don't think this example works; it's just the usual $L^2(\mathbb R)$ as a Hilbert space. The induced norm of $f(x)=\sin(ax)$ would be infinite.

Comment: There should be 1/R in your inner product definition.