# Is there only one separable Hilbert space of infinite dimension?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

The Hilbert dimension of a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ is defined as the cardinality of its total orthonormal basis. Moreover, two Hilbert spaces (over the same field) have the same Hilbert dimension,if and only if they are isomorphic.

A Hilbert space is separable if and only if it admits a countable orthonormal basis. However, the cardinality of the basis determines the Hilbert dimension, and hence the Hilbert space (for a given field, say $\mathbb{C}$). Therefore, there is only one separable Hilbert space of infinite dimension?

**EDIT**: by "only one" meaning that they are isomorphic as Hilbert spaces.

Comment: Up to the natural notion of isomorphism, yes.

Comment: First of all, you should clarify what you mean by "only one Hilbert space". For example, $L^2([0,1])$ and $\ell^2(\Bbb N)$ are indeed isomorphic as Hilbert spaces, but it is unusual to call these spaces "the same space".

Comment: take $\ell^2$ and $L^2$ these are different spaces but isomomrphic

Comment: @Renormaliser: If $H_1$ and $H_2$ have orthogonal bases of the same cardinality, then $H_1$ and $H_2$ are isometric. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/524203/uncountable-orthonormal-system-in-hilbert-spaces)  is a posting that may be relevant to the you